# Flask Moment with Mustache

Tags: python, flask, mustache, momentjs

I am trying the display the backend column which is stored as UTC time in local time.
Rendering page using Mustache

In Mustache below is the field template

```
<td id="cur_loc_time_{{id}}">{{current_location.last_updated_timestamp}}</td>
```

I am trying to show this field as locale time using Flask Moment
In the HTML I tried the below but it is showing UTC time only.

```
alert(moment(($("#cur_loc_time_1").text())).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
```

I was debugging to check whether it displays correct time for one element.
The value from the database is `2014-06-21 10:56:46`
But the output was
[image]

I also tried adding in the Mustache Template but still it did not work.
If I add in the HTML page as

```
{{ moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') }}
```

It displays the time correctly of the local.

Please advise if I have missed anything!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different way to handle this instead of using FlaskMoment package with Mustache. I have used the [pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz) python package

I simply wrote a function in the models which is the definition of the data retrieved from the backend. So my application works like this. Stores the date and timestamp in UTC in the database. But while displaying or returning in APIs it returns in users locale time. Below is the code snippet of the function. Basically I wanna convert UTC to IST

```
local_timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')

def utc_to_ist(value):
    timestamp_utc=value
    timestamp_utc=pytz.utc.localize(timestamp_utc)
    return timestamp_utc.astimezone(local_timezone)
```

Based on the local_timezone value that is timezone location it localize the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the date format explicitly:

```
alert(moment($("#cur_loc_time_1").text(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
```

Comment: No it did not work!! It is just displaying the UTC time June 22nd 2014, 6:11:31 pm in this format!! Thanks for the input!! Let me try something !!